# Make [py2to3] a synonym of [2to3]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

We have both [py2to3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/py2to3) and [2to3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/2to3). To the best of my knowledge, they reference the same conversion tool. [py2to3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/py2to3) has fewer questions and less info, so I think it should be a synonym of the [2to3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/2to3) tag.

Comment: *2to3* is also the official name, according to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html).

Comment: I prefer python-2to3

Comment: We also have python2to3 (distinct from python-2to3) which is about differences between versions, not the tool.

Comment: @Braiam so do I... Done.